# Ipython ? Shell

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7, ipython

Whenever I use ipython and want to look up the docs on some object I use the ? command after the object. However, once I'm viewing the docs I can't go back to the previous ipython shell. Is there some easy keystrokes to do this? It is getting really annoying having to exit out of the ipython shell every time I need to look up an object or function. Im using ipython in ubuntu if that helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just press `q` if you want to exit from the docs in `Ipython`